# Index for join query with where clause PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have to optimize the following query with the help of indexes.

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM first f 
JOIN second s on f.attributex_id = s.id 
WHERE f.attributex_id IS NOT NULL AND f.attributey_id IS NULL
ORDER BY s.month ASC LIMIT 100;
```

Further infos:

- `attributex_id` is a foreign key pointing to `second.id`
- `attributey_id` is a foreign key pointing to another table not used in the query
- Changing the query is not an option
- Most entries (98%) in first the following will be true `f.attributex_id IS NOT NULL`. Same for the second condition `f.attributey_id IS NULL`

I tried to add as index as follows.

```sql
CREATE INDEX index_for_first
    ON first (attributex_id, attributey_id)
    WHERE attributex_id IS NOT NULL AND (attributey_id IS NULL)
```

But the index is not used (checked via Explain Analyze) when executing the query. What kind of indexes would I need to optimize the query and what am I doing wrong with the above index?
Does an index on `s.month` make sense, too (`month` is unique)?

Comment: Change `select f.*` to `select attributex_id, attributey_id` and see if your index is used.

Comment: First thing I'd do is put an index on the join foreign key so first.attributex_id

Comment: If nearly all records in `first` have non-null `attributex_id`, the planner may choose to ignore the index, because your query selects all columns from `first`.  A table scan may be cheaper than using the index and doing a row lookup for each matching record.

Comment: You looked at the explain analyze, but you need to show it to us as well.

Comment: @dfundako changing the query is not an option

Comment: @BillJetzer I added some more infos to the question. Indeed most rows in first will have non-null `attributex_id`. does that mean an index on `f.attributey_id` with `is NULL` is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query text and the fact that nearly all records in `first` satisfy the `where` clause, what you're essentially trying to do is

1. identify the 100 `second` records with the lowest `month` value
2. output the contents of the related records in the `first` table.

To achieve that you can create indexes on

1. `second.month`
2. `first.attributex_id`

#### Caveats

Since this query must be optimized, it's safe to say there are many rows in both tables.  Since there are only 12 months in the year, the output of the query is probably not deterministic (*i.e.*, it may return a different set of rows each time it's run, even if there is no activity in either table between runs) since many records likely share the same value for `month`.  Adding "tie breaker" column(s) to the index on `second` *may* help, though your `order by` only includes `month`, so no guarantees.  Also, if `second.month` can have `null` values, [you'll need to decide whether those `null` values should collate first or last among values.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html)

Also, this particular query is not the only one being run against your data.  These indexes will take up disk space and incrementally slow down writes to the tables. If you have a dozen queries that perform poorly, you might fall into a trap of creating a couple indexes to help each one individually and that's not a solution that scales well.

Finally, you stated that

> changing the query is not an option

Does that mean you're not allowed to change the *text* of the query, or the *output* of the query?

I *personally* feel like re-writing the query to select `from second` and then `join first` makes the goal of the query more obvious.  The fact that your initial instinct was to add indexes to `first` lends credence to this idea.  If the query were written as follows, it would have been more obvious that the thing to do is facilitate efficient access to the tiny set of rows in `second` that you're interested in:

```sql
...
from second s
join first f ...
where ...
order by s.month asc limit 100;
```